# Interpolation not working on Rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

For some reason the code I have included below does not interpolate the variables into the template. It simply copies the file over verbatim. I cannot figure out why.

https://gist.github.com/60484f7b57b06b6eb3e3

The Rails version is 2.3.4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there NO interpolation going on, or is the interpolation just done with blanks? Reason I ask is, that I think

> class <%= @model_name.camelize %>

should be written as

> class <%= model_name.camelize %>

HTH

/Carsten

Comment: You are right. I had a few issues most of which spawned from :collision => :force, seemingly, not doing its job.

It seems that if the file is there (and it doesn't overwrite it) it will simply perform the actions (in this case interpolation) on that file.

(Note: Yes, in the code :collision is commented out, but that was just one of MANY versions.)